# How to make page to scroll horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I made these three sections, and I want them each to be **stretched through the whole screen**, I managed to do that with `width`, but I don't know how to set the `height` to be 100% of the screen, and the main thing I want them to scroll horizontally, not vertically as usual. Can my code be fixed?

Take a look at the snippet bellow:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.element {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.element2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.element3 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #111;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.element p {
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Bebas Neue";
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
}
.element2 p {
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Bebas Neue";
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
}
.element3 p {
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Bebas Neue";
  font-size: 50px;
  color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <p>Element #1</p>
</div>

<div class="element2">
  <p>Element #2</p>
</div>

<div class="element3">
  <p>Element #3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using flexbox, and set both `html` and `body` to `height: 100%;`

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.element {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
.element1 { background: pink; }
.element2 { background: lightgreen; }
.element3 { background: lightblue; }
```

```html
<div class="element element1">Element #1</div>
<div class="element element2">Element #2</div>
<div class="element element3">Element #3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make all your sections `inline-block` so that they come besides one another.

`.element { display: inline-block; }`

Comment: but how to make them full height of the browser or screen, and how to make it scroll vertically?

Comment: Set each element's height to `100vh`: `.element { height: 100vh; }`

Comment: an make it scroll horizontally?